# Error when using multiple datasets to plot polygon annotation on ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a forest plot for a meta-analysis using ggplot2. I want to manually add a skewed diamond shape (asymmetric on the y-scale) to represent an effect size and confidence interval.

I can draw the forest plot and add four segments to create the diamond but this doesn't give a nice clear, sharp diamond. Instead I've used geom_polygon with a set of co-ordinates in a second dataframe. When I try to write to pdf I receive the following error

```
summarydiamond <- data.frame(
  x = c(sleepstress.r.CI.L, sleepstress.r.estimate, sleepstress.r.CI.U, sleepstress.r.estimate, sleepstress.r.CI.L),
  y = c(-1, -1.5, -1, -0.5, -1)
  )

forest.plot <- 
  dat.sleepstress %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = rev(key.pairing), y = r, ymin = r.CI.lower, ymax = r.CI.upper))+
  geom_errorbar(width = 0.5) + 
  geom_point(aes(size = r.weights)) + 
  scale_size(range = c(1, 7)) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0) +  
  theme_minimal() + 
  coord_flip() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") + 
    labs(x = "", y = "Correlation coefficient") +
  theme(text = element_text(size=14)) +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=rev) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = paste0(format(round(r, 2),nsmall = 2),
                               " (", 
                               format(round(r.CI.lower, 2),nsmall = 2),
                               ", ",
                               format(round(r.CI.upper, 2),nsmall = 2),
                               ")"), 
                y = 0.85), 
            hjust="inward") +
  geom_polygon(aes(x=x, y=y), data = summarydiamond) 

pdf(file = 'forestplot.pdf', width = 10, height = 10)         
forest.plot
dev.off()
```

Output:

```
forest.plot
```

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'r.CI.lower' not found

I've tried adding the `data=` argument to all of the `geom_` calls but this doesn't fix it.

Comment: The dataframe `summarydiamond` should also have `r.CI.lower`. That is why you are getting that error. We can not reproduce your error as no data was shared!

Comment: A fix would be to add argument `inherit.aes = FALSE` to `geom_polygon`.

Comment: Thanks to both. @stefan - yours was the solution I went for and works exactly as hoped. Please answer the question and I'll upvote it.